# Jquery tab. Check if any of them is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have some tabs. All are collapsed by default. If the user click on a button first tab opens. I figured out that part:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showFirstTab').on('click', function() {
        var tabObj = jQuery('#podcast-tabs li:first a');
        tabObj.tab('show');
        var programId = tabObj.data('programid');

        jQuery('#calendar-' + programId).fullCalendar('render');
    });
});
```

Now I need to check if any tab is open, and click again on the same button, all tabs should collapse. I was thinking in use a variable to save the state, but not sure if library provides already a solution for this.

Comment: Maybe something like this ? https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: That one is an accordion :)

Comment: Ok so I didn't understood the "collapse" part of your post. Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if any tab is open, by using the [`tabsactivate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event:

```
var isActive = false;
$(".podcast-tabs").on("tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    isActive = true;
});
```

Now, inside your click code check for that variable and if true close all tabs using [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) like:

```
if (isActive)
    $("#podcast-tabs").tabs("option", "active", false);
```